# Check if string exists in a web page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use curl to detect whether a piece of text exists in the source code of a remote webpage. For example, I'm trying to see if this string exists in the source:

```html
<!-- BEGIN TEST CODE -->
```

If it exists in the HTML source code of a remote webpage (say, [example.com](http://www.example.com/)) I want to echo "yes". If it doesn't exist in the source, I want it to echo "no".

This is what I've tried so far:

```php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$text = curl_exec($ch);

$test = strpos($text, "<!-- BEGIN TEST CODE -->");
if ($test==false)
{
    echo "yes";
}else{
    echo "no";
}
```

When I run it, it always outputs "yes". **What's wrong in my code, and how should I do it correctly?**

Comment: can you post the code you have so far, so that we can recommend how to make it do what you want?

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problems are you having? Have you looked at the PHP cURL documentation (php.net/curl)? Are you having trouble getting the source code, searching it, or both?

Comment: What I have tried will not bring up if it has it in the source code or not. I keep getting a blank results. I managed to save over what I had. I will try to recreate what I had so far

Comment: To be certain that you have a good string to start with, echo or print_r the $fileurl variable. Once you know it is there, and as you expected, try strpos again. If the absolute beginning of the string is <!-- BEGIN TEST CODE --> then strpos will be zero, and therefore evaluate to "false", so try `$is_a_test =( strpos($fileurl, "<!-- BEGIN TEST CODE -->")!==false);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two functions you need are `cURL` and `strpos()`.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$text = curl_exec($ch);
$test = strpos($text, "<!-- BEGIN TEST CODE -->");
if ($test==false)
{
    echo "no";
}
else
{
    echo "yes";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, used test instead of $test.

Comment: 5th line I added ; it has no errors but my test website I'm always getting no and it's in the source code.

Comment: Yes and also fixed the test to $test and I always get a yes on any URL even the page it has it on it. Trying to see why I know it's right there.

Comment: Thank you so far. I'm getting a no always now. Even if my test page has it or not.

Comment: It's working for me...are you sure the URL is exactly correct? (Having a www. or not makes a difference)

Comment: I'm sorry it works but for some reason on a real page that "line" im looking for is at line 1126 and it doesn't seem to find it but a normal short html page it does.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong, sorry. Hope someone else can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$is_a_test = strpos($the_page_text, "<!-- BEGIN TEST CODE -->");`?

PHP strpos() documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: How would I make it search a URL?

Comment: have you tried file_get_contents? http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php