# Check if a certain string exists on a AngularJS web page by using php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I saw this answer Check if string exists in a web page - [Check if string exists in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576772/check-if-string-exists-in-a-web-page) and it works

but what about checking for a string on an external web page that is using Angularjs? Is it still possible to search with php curl or another language should be used.

Comment: The same code can be applied also to any "html" page that embeds Angular content. Beware that you **can never** search for dynamic text that gets rendered at runtime based on code evaluation

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, because the problem is that AngularJS is a clientside SPA framework. You would need to parse the JS and run it like a browser would, in order to determine the content of the page. I don't know of any PHP libs that do this.

The alternative without "just php" would be to use a web crawler. There are a couple out there that solve this exact problem. You could then technically use PHP to read the output of the webcrawler program. But then you might not need PHP at all...

If you're going to do any sort of serious page reading I would just use a web crawler/browser to do this. Why reinvent the wheel(browser) when you can just use it?